# Async Create hanging while publishing observable

Tags: c#, asynchronous, observable, reactive-programming, system.reactive

Consider the following code:

```
var xs = Observable.Create<Unit>(async o => 
{
    await Task.Delay(10);
    o.OnError(new Exception());
}).Replay().RefCount();

xs.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
xs.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x), ex => Console.WriteLine(ex.Message));
await xs.DefaultIfEmpty();
```

The sequence above doesn't throw any exceptions and never completes.

I made the following observations:

1. Removing the first subscription enables error propagation - exception is thrown in `Subscribe` context (last line)
2. Removing `.Replay().RefCount()` enables error propagation - exception is thrown in `Subscribe` context (last line)
3. Removing `await Task.Delay(10)` enables error propagation - exception is thrown in `OnError` call (within `Create` method). Surprisingly, switching two `Subscribe` methods makes exception thrown at `Subscribe` context (last line).

That being said, I am asking whether the following issues are by design:

1. Observable sequence in the above scenario never being completed
2. The fact that exception is sometimes thrown inside `Create` method, and other times - at `Subscribe` context.

If this is by design, what would you recommend as a workaround? How do I publish my sequences so that all of my clients (observers) can safely handle exceptions in this case? Current behavior seems so arbitrary, especially for library creators. It also makes debugging very painful. Please advise.

Comment: What do you mean? I am using `async` all the way down. It is not shown in the code snippet above, but even if you wrap it all within async method returning `Task`, it will behave the same as I described.

Comment: This sure looks like a Heisenbug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First to answer your questions:

1. No it's not by design. It is a bug.
2. "Workaround" is to not mix TPL and Reactive. You can hit funny things like this.

The following works as expected:

```
var xs = Observable.Throw<Unit>(new Exception())
    .Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10))
    .Replay()
    .RefCount();
```

This causes exceptions to be raised on the first `.Subscribe` and the `await xs.DefaultIfEmpty()` call. You get two exceptions because of the delay: Multiple threads are running.

---

As for why this is happening, here's a start:

That first Subscribe code basically translates to the follow. ([See source](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Observable.Extensions.cs)):

```
xs.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x), Stubs.Throw, Stubs.Nop);

public static class Stubs
{

    public static readonly Action Nop = delegate
    {
    };

    public static readonly Action<Exception> Throw = delegate (Exception ex)
    {
        var edi = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex);
        edi.Throw();
    };
}
```

If you breakpoint into the `Stubs` class, you'll see that it gets in there and tries to throw the exception. However, the exception doesn't bubble up, most likely due to some weird TPL/ReplaySubject interaction.

Answer (score 2):

I think this may have to do with the dynamics of pipeline teardown.

This is our expected behavior for `Replay` (which uses `ReplaySubject` internally).

[image: marble diagram]

However, whether the error notification propagates before the pipeline tears down seems to be a matter of of timing. When using a `ReplaySubject` directly, it works as expected, even with `OnError` in `Subscribe`.

```
        var xs = new ReplaySubject<Unit>();
        var sxs = Observable.Create<Unit>(async o =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(10);
            o.OnError(new Exception("ERR"));

        }).Subscribe(xs);


        xs.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x), ex => Console.WriteLine(ex.Message));
        xs.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x), ex => Console.WriteLine(ex.Message));

        xs.DefaultIfEmpty().Wait();

        Console.WriteLine("-end-");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Using `IConnectableObservable` seems to lead to Heisenbugs during teardown.

Comment: Seems like your example does not work either. One of the necessary conditions is to have at least one subscription without an error handler. If you remove the second action from one of your subscriptions, the sequence will never complete.

Comment: If you remove the error handling action, the error is thrown by the anonymous observer instead - so you never get to any of the other methods.

Comment: That's only true if you get lucky. If you run the code several times, you will notice that sometimes the error does not propagate - it simply hangs. This probably has to do with some weird race condition in the guts of Rx?

Answer (score 1):

The problem still exists with the current version of the [System.Reactive](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive/) library (5.0.0). I made some progress identifying its cause. The problem is related with the naughty subscribers that omit the `onError` handler. When this handler is omitted, the Rx puts something like this in its place:

```
void OnError(Exception error) => throw error;
```

The error is just rethrown synchronously on the thread that invoked the handler! This has the implication that no other subscriber after the naughty one will receive the `OnError` notification, because an observable notifies all of its subscribers sequentially and synchronously.

```
var subject = new Subject<Unit>();
subject.Subscribe(); // Naughty subscriber
subject.OnError(new ApplicationException("@")); // Throws synchronously
```

([Try it on Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t7wJ8B))

Normally this is not a problem, because most notifications coming from built-in Rx operators are invoked asynchronously from `ThreadPool` threads. This means that there is no way for the client code to catch the exceptions caused by naughty subscribers. And so the exceptions remain unhandled, and are crashing the process. Which is not an ideal behavior for a commercial application, but it is surely much nicer than a hanging process, waiting for a notification that will never come. I am saying this to make it clear that the problem we are trying to solve here is how to make the application crash consistently. When an error occurs and we have a naughty subscriber, crashing the process is the desired behavior. So let's find a way to make it happen with the `Observable.Create` too.

The problem with the native `Observable.Create(Func<IObserver<TResult>, Task>)` method is that invoking the asynchronous lambda produces a `Task`, and the tasks have embedded error handling features. So an exception inside the lambda doesn't escalate automatically to an unhandled exception that crashes the process. My first attempt to fix the `Observable.Create` method was to `await` the task, catch the exception, try to propagate it again through the `observer.OnError` method, and if this attempt failed then rethrow the exception on the `ThreadPool` and crash the process for good. But this idea is flawed because only the first invocation of the `observer.OnError` throws. Subsequent invocations are doing nothing, because the built-in observers respect the Rx contract, which disallows multiple `OnError` notifications. So the try/catch must target specifically the `observer.OnError` invocation, not the whole asynchronous lambda in general. Which means that we need a wrapper of the supplied observer. The implementation below is based on this idea:

```
public static IObservable<TSource> CreateObservableEx<TSource>(
    Func<IObserver<TSource>, CancellationToken, Task> subscribeAsync)
{
    return Observable.Create<TSource>(async (observer, cancellationToken) =>
    {
        var innerObserver = Observer.Create<TSource>(observer.OnNext,
            PropagateError, observer.OnCompleted);

        try { await subscribeAsync(innerObserver, cancellationToken); }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            PropagateError(ex);
        }

        void PropagateError(Exception error)
        {
            try { observer.OnError(error); }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw(ex));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Usage example:

```
var xs = CreateObservableEx<Unit>(async (o, ct) =>
{
    await Task.Delay(10, ct);
    o.OnError(new Exception());
}).Replay().RefCount();

xs.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
xs.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x), ex => Console.WriteLine(ex.Message));
await xs.DefaultIfEmpty();
```

([Try it on Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VdFKJf))

Output:

```xml
System.Exception (Unhandled)
```